# List WP Categories with Custom field Values

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy, wp-list-categories

I added a Field Group using ACF plugin to the default WP Category Add/Edit screen so that I can add additional values to categories such as category icon/background image, checkbox to displayed on home or not and assign it as one of the popular categories.

[image]

I'm trying to list all the categories on the homepage based on popularity checkbox along with their icon and background image.

I have two image fields such as category_icon for storing category icon and category_bg_image for storing category background image.

Below is the code where I'm able to list the Categories however the custom field values of icon and background image isn't showing.

```
 if (have_posts() ) :
  while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

$args=array( 

'hide_empty' => '0',
'meta_key' => 'popular_services_category'
 );

  $categories=get_categories($args);

   foreach($categories as $category) {
  echo '<li>'  . $category->name . '</li>';

      global $post;
      $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'category');
      
      if( !empty($terms) )
      {
      $term = array_pop($terms);
      $custom_field = get_field('category_icon', 'category_' . $term->term_id );
     
      echo '<li>'  . $custom_field['url'] . '</li>';
     
   }      
   }
   endwhile;
```

Comment: What does your `$terms ` is returning ? what does `$term` looks like ? does `$custom_field` is returning something ? did you tried to replace `'category_'` with `''term_'` ?

Comment: I just a print_r(terms) and it did not return anything. $custom_field too did not return anything. Changing to 'term_' did not do anything. Let me know where I'm wrong?

Comment: if your `$terms` is empty, no need to go deeper... What about your `$categories` variable ?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue of showing the icon and background image by not going into the $terms. Just below the listing of categories in <li>, I used  the code - `$custom_field = get_field('category_icon', $category->taxonomy . '_' . $category->term_id );`  @Pof

Comment: @RakeshOjha, if you wouldn't mind, please post an answer to your question outlining the changes you made to get it to work. That way, in the future, if someone has a similar issue, and comes across this question they can easily find the solution. Once you do that, be sure to click the checkmark next to the answer to select it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for your suggestion. I've posted the actual code that helped me achieve what I was looking for. Hope this helps people like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue with little modification and I am posting it here for others to be helpful.

```
  if (have_posts() ) :
  while (have_posts() ) : the_post();

      $args=array( 
        'hide_empty' => '0',
        'meta_key' => 'popular_services_category'
                 );

          $categories=get_categories($args);

      foreach($categories as $category) 
         {
             echo '<li>'  . $category->name . '</li>';

             $image = get_field('category_icon', $category->taxonomy . '_' . 
             $category->term_id );
             $image_bg = get_field('category_bg_image', $category->taxonomy . '_' . $category->term_id );

             // Check if the image exists
             if ( $image ) : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />
                <img src="<?php echo $image_bg['url']; ?>" />
             endif; 
          }
   endwhile;
```